# wpf image source depending on object property

Tags: wpf, image, binding

I have a boolean property in my class, say:

```
private bool isFolder;
public bool IsFolder{ get; set; }
```

and I have an image in xaml:

```
<Image Source="..">
```

I would like that image to have one imageSource when the IsFolder is true and another one - when it's false. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`DataTriggers`** are used for that purpose only.

Set default value in case IsFolder is false *(bind it to NotFolderImage property)*. In case IsFolder value is set to true, set the source to other value *(FolderImage in this case)*.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding NotFolderImage}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFolder}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding FolderImage}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Also, make sure underlying ViewModel class is implementing [**INotifyPropertyChanged**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx) event so that change in IsFolder property is propagated to UI.

Comment: Wow, Thanks for the lightning fast response!